# How to catch an exception thrown in ctypes?

Tags: python, exception, ctypes, abort

I am working with some C code called from Python using ctypes.  Somewhere in the bowels of the C library, an exception is occurring and/or abort() is being called.  Is there any way I can catch this in my Python caller code? (Platform is Linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to setup a signal handler on SIGABRT to handle the signal caused by abort().
However, failed assertions might go along with corrupted memory and other bad things - there's usually a reason why an assertion failed. So usually terminating the applications is the best thing you can do (except displaying/logging an error in your handler before terminating).

Comment: Will using the Python signal module allow me to trap a SIGABRT signalled from the C library called through ctypes?

Comment: I have tried this now, and calling abort() in my C code does not signal SIGABRT to my handler in Python.  So I'll have to set up my signal handler in the C code too.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Paul McGuire, I am also facing the same issue as you faced in this aspect. So could you please guide me how could I solve this. code snippets or examples are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.