# intercept c-assert with python unittest

Tags: c++, python, unit-testing, assertions

I want to test a class written in C++ using unittest in python. If the argument of the constructor of the class is wrong the class raises an assertion (using `<cassert>`)

I am trying with:

```
self.assertRaises(SystemExit, ROOT.MyClass, 'invalid_tune')
```

but it doesn't seems to work, I get:

```
python test.py
python: ../Root/MyClass.cxx:53: MyClass::MyClass(std::string): Assertion `false' failed.
Aborted
```

Comment: Is the class yours? If so, it might be a good idea to raise an exception instead of calling `assert`, which just results in an abort, about which you can do very little. Also, it won't have any effect if the `NDEBUG` macro is defined.

Comment: I was expecting this comment. Yes, it's mine, but no: I can't use exception. Policy, don't ask me why.

Comment: That is a terrible policy! Exceptions are the idimatic way of dealing with construction problems in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I agree, they prefer exit status, but this is another story... I would like to find a solution to *this* problem

Comment: then you could replace the assert with an ``exit``, that at least allows the program to perform some cleanup.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844121/how-to-catch-an-exception-thrown-in-ctypes